# Why is the image of the evaluation homomorphism with respect to a transcendental alpha an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$, we see that $\phi_{\alpha}$ yields an isomorphism of $F[x]$ with a subdomain of $E$ because $\ker{\phi_{\alpha}} = 0$ since there exists no $f \in F[x]$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$. According to Fraleigh it follows that $\phi_{\alpha} [F[x]]$ is an integral domain. I am having a difficult time understanding why this is true. Could someone please explain? Furthermore, why is it that the the field of quotients is the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: Since $\phi_\alpha$ is a ring homomorphism and by what you said that $F[x]\cong \phi_\alpha(F[x])$, then $\phi_\alpha(F[x])$ is also an integral domain since $F[x]$ is an integral domain (in fact, it is a Euclidean domain since $F$ is a field). For your second question, what field of quotients are you referring to? Is it $F(x)$? If it is, since $\alpha$ is transcendental, we have in fact $F(\alpha)\cong F(x)$ and since $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest subfield containing $F$ and $\alpha$ then by the isomorphism we have the answer to your 2nd question.